# How transform this query in impala?

Tags: sql, cloudera, impala

This is an example in SQL but I need transform this process in Cloudera Imapala

```
UPDATE e_solutions_owner.nueva_tabla
    SET de_canal_venta_distr = 'CAV ENDESA X'
    where de_canal_venta_distr = 'CAT VENTAS SII';
```

How could i create it??

Thanks

Comment: Normally there is no `UPDATE` for Impala unless you have Kudu. If you do not have Kudu, you need to write data into a tmp table, compare target and source and do a 2 step process to update the data.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned you have Kudu or not. So I am assuming you don't have Kudu which supports UPDATE. You can do it in a three steps. I created a temp table and replaced final table.
Step1 - Load the 'updated' data into a tmp table

```
create table if not exists e_solutions_owner.tmp_nueva_tabla as
select 
col1,col2...
de_canal_venta_distr
from e_solutions_owner.nueva_tabla
where ifnull(de_canal_venta_distr,'x') <> 'CAT VENTAS SII'
union 
select 
col1,col2...
'CAV ENDESA X' de_canal_venta_distr
from e_solutions_owner.nueva_tabla
where de_canal_venta_distr = 'CAT VENTAS SII'
```

Step2 - insert overwrite data into main table.
`insert overwrite e_solutions_owner.nueva_tabla select * from e_solutions_owner.tmp_nueva_tabla`

Step3 - Drop the temp table.
`drop table e_solutions_owner.tmp_nueva_tabla`

Comment: Np, I havent KUDU. Thank you @koushik roy. Good idea! in two queries.